# Atoi() and strtol() not working correctly in C

Tags: c

Basically I want to check if the time that I wrote is valid or not 
I typed this string: `20:40:30` and I get as a result: `No`

When I debugged the problem it turned out that the 
`atoi` is not working correctly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char Input[20] = { '\0' };
    scanf("%s", &Input);

    char sub1[2] = { '\0' };
    char sub2[2] = { '\0' };
    char sub3[2] = { '\0' };

    strncpy(sub1, Input, 2);
    strncpy(sub2, Input + 3, 2);
    strncpy(sub3, Input + 6, 2);

    int H = atoi(sub1);
    int M = atoi(sub2);
    int S = atoi(sub3);

    int count = 0;
    if (H >= 0 && H < 24) count++;
    if (M >= 0 && M < 60) count++;
    if (S >= 0 && S < 60) count++;

    if (count == 3)
        printf("Yes);
    else
        printf("No");

    return 0;
}
```

I tried `strtol` too and still the same problem .

Comment: It's not atoi that is not working correctly, that just a consequence of the earlier error, which is that you are using strncpy incorrectly. And scanf doesn't need the `&` when being used to read a string.

Comment: If I were the writer of the functions, I would feel too sad since someone says they.are broken due to the fact that most of all C codes utilize them.

Comment: `char sub1[2]` can only represent a 1-digit number

Comment: the posted code. when run through the compiler results in 4 ERROR messages and 2 WARNING messages.  So that posted code NEVER ran.   Please post the actual code your using.  Perhaps via a select/copy/paste sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the arrays into which you copy the string fragments are not long enough to hold 2 characters plus a null terminator.
- `strncpy()` does not set a nul terminator in the destination if the source string has at least as many characters as the size argument specifies. Making the destination arrays longer and initializing the to `0` would suffice to solve the problem here, but the semantics `strncpy()` are confusing and error prone so it would be best to avoid using the function.
- you do not verify the actual contents of the string: `"1x+ 2=3b"` would be considered correct as well as `"abcdefgh"` because you only check that the numbers if any starting at offsets 0, 3 and 6 are in the proper range.

Here is a more effective verification:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char Input[20], sub1[3], sub2[3], sub3[3];
    int pos;
    char c;

    /* read a string of at most 19 characters */
    if (scanf("%19s", Input) != 1) {
        printf("No: input error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* extract 3 fields of at most 2 digits separated by ':'
     * verify that all characters have been consumed
     * verify that 8 characters have been consumed 
     */
    if (sscanf(Input, "%2[0-9]:%2[0-9]:%2[0-9]%n%c", sub1, sub2, sub3, &pos, &c) != 3 || pos != 8) {
        printf("No: format error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int H = atoi(sub1);
    int M = atoi(sub2);
    int S = atoi(sub3);

    /* no need to test for negative values since we already verified
     *  that the fields have 2 digits
     */
    if (H < 24 && M < 60 && S < 60)
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No: values out of range\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the hour, minute, second in the input string can be single digits.   The posted code seems to not handle that condition.  Also, an invalid input, like `00:59:59` would not be rejected.  Also,  1:1:1 is a valid time but would be rejected

Comment: @user3629249: how is `00:59:59` an invalid input? The code posted in the question makes the silent assumption that at least the hour and the minute must have 2 digits, so I assumed the time had a mandatory format of `HH:MM:SS` if such is not the case, it is easy to remove the test on `pos`.

Comment: Ahhh,  I see, the hour has the range 00...23,  My error

Comment: why do we need int pos and char c ?

Comment: @Gaston: `pos` is set by `sscanf()` to the offset after the second, which must be 8 for the format `HH:MM:SS`. This check rejects strings with a single digit for hour, minute or second. `c` is used for the `%c` conversion which is supposed to fail. If this conversion succeeds, it indicates there is at least one extra character after the seconds field, which is an error. An alternative would be to test if `Input[pos] == '\0'`

Comment: One last question @chqrlie : how does the %2[0-9] work exactly

Comment: @Gaston: `%2[0-9]` means read and store into the destination array, at least 1 and at most 2 characters that must be in the set `'0'..'9'`. The format string `"%2[0-9]:%2[0-9]:%2[0-9]%n%c"` reads 3 numbers composed of at most 2 digits each and separated by `:`, `%n` stores the offset into `pos`, which I verify to be exactly `8`, and `%c` will fail if the string has been converted completely. `pos == 8` means each of the 3 numbers had exactly 2 digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot @chqrlie

Answer (score 2):

`strncpy()` does not place the final `'\0'` when the
max number of characters is reached.
You have to place it manually, and ensure there is **enough
storage** for it.
(of course, if the resulting buffer is already filled with zeros
you don't have to place it explicitly, but in the general case
you have to ensure that)

In your attempt, `atoi()` will find *anything* after the two characters
you copied; this is a buffer overrun and this sequence of character
will probably not look like an integer.

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
     char Input[20]={'\0'};
     scanf("%s",Input);


     char sub1[3]={'\0'}; // 2 --> 3 for the final '\0'
     char sub2[3]={'\0'}; // note that since these arrays are partially
     char sub3[3]={'\0'}; // initialised, they contain some zeros in the
                          // remaining locations.


     strncpy(sub1,Input,2);
     sub1[2]='\0'; // useless here since sub1 is filled with zeros
     strncpy(sub2,Input+3,2);
     sub2[2]='\0'; // useless here since sub2 is filled with zeros
     strncpy(sub3,Input+6,2);
     sub3[2]='\0'; // useless here since sub3 is filled with zeros


     int H=atoi(sub1);
     int M=atoi(sub2);
     int S=atoi(sub3);

     int count=0;
     if (H>=0 && H<24)count++;
     if (M>=0 && M<60)count++;
     if (S>=0 && S<60)count++;

    if (count==3)printf("Yes\n");
    else printf("No\n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your modification will correct the behavior for `20:30:40` but will still print `Yes` for many invalid strings.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes I agree with you. But let's address one problem at a time. I thought the question was focused on `atoi()` not behaving as expected in the specific case of the test as it was described, nothing more. After that, parsing a string is another problem, and from that point of view I largely prefer your solution to the original one (here, +1 for that ;^)

Comment: The atoi() did not work for me because I didn't have enough space for the strings. It was then printing strange numbers @prog-fh

Comment: @Gaston The code I posted was build with the address sanitizer, and ran without any problem so there is enough space for the stings (at least with in input string you provide in your question). Look at the comments I wrote carefully in this code to explain why I extended the storage from 2 to 3 elements. Instead of giving something totally different I tried to stay as close as possible to your question because it was precisely focused on an issue around `atoi()` (not a general problem).